# "could not import from "iphone" the device was disconnected

Tags: mac, iphone, scanning

[image]

I have tried to use Continuity Camera to take scan.
My step:
Open Preview App
File import from iphone
scan documents
and after I use my Iphone 11 to take the photo, the moment I click save, it crashes on my iphone and the Macbook gives me a message below.

Strangely, I have tried to take a photo and it works perfectly. But not scan.